# Cannot deselect first selected cell in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox, multi-select

I'm trying to implement a multi-selection tableview in iOS. How it works:

Every item has a checkbox on the left. 
When the user taps this checkbox the tableview switches to multi-selection mode.
The user can now select additional items by tapping on the checkbox or anywhere in the cells. This is all working fine save for 1 thing:

Say I have 3 items in my list: A, B and C ordered alphabetically. I tap A's checkbox to enter multi-select mode and proceed to add B and C as well. If I tap B or C again the item is deselected and their respective checkboxes become unchecked again. If I attempt to deselect A before B and C are deselected however, the cell still looks selected. A does get removed from my array of selected items however. This always happens with the item I use to enter multi-select mode.

My code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNotificationTableViewCell
    let notification = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNotification

    if(tableView.allowsMultipleSelection){
        if(!selectedNotificationsArray.containsObject(notification.notification_id)){
            tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
            selectedNotificationsArray.addObject(notification.notification_id)
            cell.selectionButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "CheckboxChecked")
        }
    }else{
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        let alert = UIAlertView(
            title: notification.scope,
            message: notification.message,
            delegate: self,
            cancelButtonTitle: LocalizedString("cancel"),
            otherButtonTitles: LocalizedString("alert_option_mark_as_read")
        )
        alert.tag = 1
        selectedNotificationsArray.addObject(notification.notification_id)
        alert.show()
    }

    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
}

func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        markSelectedNotificationsAsRead()
    }else{
        selectedNotificationsArray.removeAllObjects()
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("deselected a cell")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNotificationTableViewCell
    let notification = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNotification

    if(selectedNotificationsArray.containsObject(notification.notification_id)){
        selectedNotificationsArray.removeObject(notification.notification_id)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        cell.selectionButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "CheckboxUnchecked")
        if(selectedNotificationsArray.count == 0){
            switchNavigationBarMode(false)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func tappedSelectionCheckbox(sender: CheckBoxButton){
    let notification = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(sender.cellIndexPath!) as! MyNotification
    print("tapped checkbox of notification with message:  " + String(notification.message))
    if(tableView.allowsMultipleSelection == false){
        switchNavigationBarMode(true)
    }
    if(selectedNotificationsArray.containsObject(notification.notification_id)){
        tableView(tableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: sender.cellIndexPath!)
    }else{
        tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: sender.cellIndexPath!)
    }
    //Redraw cell so that the checkbox is updated
    tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: sender.cellIndexPath!).setNeedsDisplay()
}

func switchNavigationBarMode(enabled: Bool){
    if(enabled){
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        backButton = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(selectAllButton, animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([markReadButton!, deleteButton!], animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.title = nil
    }else{
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        self.navigationItem.title = "Notifications"
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(nil, animated: true)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyNotificationTableViewCell
    let notification = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNotification
    cell.messageLabel.text = notification.message

    // Unread notifications are bold
    if(notification.read_date.isEmpty){
        cell.messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS-Bold", size: 17)
    }

    if(selectedNotificationsArray.containsObject(notification.notification_id)){
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        cell.selectionButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "CheckboxChecked")

    }else{
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        cell.selectionButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "CheckboxUnchecked")
    }
    cell.selectionButton.cellIndexPath = indexPath
    cell.selectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyNotificationViewController.tappedSelectionCheckbox(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'"
    let utcDateTimeObject = dateFormatter.dateFromString(notification.send_date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let shortTimestamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(utcDateTimeObject!)
    cell.timestampLabel.text = shortTimestamp
    let scope = notification.scope
    switch(scope){
    case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_DEVICE:

        break
    case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_INVENTORY:

        break
    case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_JOURNAL:

        break
    case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_PROTOCOL:

        break
    case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_SUPPLIES:

        break
    case Constants.NOTIFICATION_SCOPE_SYSTEM:

        break
    default:
        break
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath within didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I would expect this to cause some buggy behaviour.

I would suggest a different more simple approach. If you UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark to show your selected cells, cellForRowAtIndexPath can check if A, B, C etc is in your data array and there for selected and add the checkmark. Then you simply need to call reloadData within didDeselectRowAtIndexPath which is much cleaner.

This is slightly changing your UI so if you strictly wish to use the grey selected style cell this will not work, but the problem seems to be calling  selectRowAtIndexPath within didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. You should to find another way to select the cell.

Comment: "You call tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath within didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. I would expect this to cause some buggy behaviour." 
I do...? Do you mean to say I'm calling it implicitly? Because my didDeselectRowAtIndexPath doesn't have a direct call to selectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: looks like you call it on line 7.

Comment: But that's inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, not the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant. If you call selectRowAtIndexPath it will implicitly call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I see. While I agree with your suggestion that using UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark is much simpeler and cleaner, it does leave me with the issue of how to enable the multi-select mode. Right now, users can enable it by ticking on of the checkboxes (similar to the Gmail app on iOS). I could implement a long press but that doesn't seem to be common practice for iOS?